# Do I need to escape INT type values in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I work at a company that's still using mysqli connection. I know that PDO is better and we should be using that but changing to that would require a lot of work that we don't have time for. Our goal is to switch the company website to Laravel sometime in the future.

I know the mysqli class also has a prepare function but it doesn't really fit into the class we made to work with mysqli.

Until then, is mysql going to convert $_POST string variables into INT or DECIMAL types or do I need to use real_escape_string on ALL variables in the sql string regardless of whether or not it's being saved to a string or INT column.

Addon question: Is real_escape_string going to protect me from injections?

Example code:

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO table
    (
         column
    )
    VALUE
    (
         " . $mysqli_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['number']) . "
    )";
$mysqli_connection->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't. Consider submitting this:

```
1=2
```

There's no sql metacharacters in there, so it won't be modified **AT ALL** by the escape function. so you'd end up with

```
... VALUES (1 = 2)
```

which would execute as

```
... VALUES (false)
```

and end up inserting integer `0` into your table.

Comment: Choosing as the correct answer because it provides a confirmation that mysql does not convert input to number.

Comment: mysql's job isn't to convert anything. it's to do with the best it can with whatever you send it. if you're worried about injection problems, then DON'T roll your own escaping/quoting systems. and especially don't use the mysql_*() functions. use mysqli or PDO with proper placeholder-using prepared statements, and then your question becomes moot

Answer (score 2):

You can use intval() PHP function for integer data before using then with mysql syntax:

```
$id = intval($id);
```

any non-numbered posts will result in a number or zero at least.

Answer (score 0):

I would escape or parameterize ANYTHING that comes through $_POST, as you can never guarantee valid values from the client side.  Better yet, validate it and the escape/parameterize it.